# Best way to fetch millions of records table using hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using mysql tables and would like to fetch more than 10 millions of data in a single query for reporting purposes.

My table might contain foreign keys as well. I am using hibernate queries for fetching the data. The querying part alone is taking around 20-30 seconds.

Is there a way I can optimise this ? Indexing the tables in mysql will be of any help?

Comment: "Is there a way I can optimise this?" Yeah, don't use Hibernate for reporting.

Comment: _Indexing the tables in mysql will be of any help?_ Off course. Without index this need to search without references. But how could you have that many data without indexes...

Comment: Hmm, I'd suspect that transferring the data takes quite some time. Check your query with just returning a count or as little data as possible. Also call explain on your query to see whether it can be optimized somewhere. That's all on the SQL side though, Hibernate would then add overhead for creating entities. If on the other hand you only select entity properties/fields and not entire entities you might as well check whether to circumvent Hibernate for that, i.e. use plain SQL instead.

Comment: How does one absorb 10m bits of informationn simultaneously?

Comment: Even the plain sql takes time, around 15-20 seconds. I have a generic reporting engine for all the tables, I am maintaining a map with hibernate columns if i have to make plain sql queries i might have to use join queries also

Comment: @Strawberry Suppose my table is for windows updates and it has around 12 million updates . The user wants to generate a graph which shows the update installed month in x axis and number of updates in y axis

Comment: Profile your code, profile the database queries, etc. etc. This is a very broad question, there's no silver bullet.

Comment: But that's just a number. It doesn't necessarily need to know the specifics of each data point.

Comment: I find it unusual that a report wishes to plot, graph, or tabulate 10 million points of data.  Are you sure you're not querying 10 million rows but generating an output of a few dozen to a few hundred data points?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setFetchSize? Hibernate is not optimized for such large quires by default so try to play around with setFetchSize (http://www.blogbyben.com/2007/07/hibernate-performance-tip-setfetchsize.html)

Comment: the fetch size will just help with pagination.